# SVG animationPath - calcMode='discrete' not honoured

Tags: svg, svg-animate

I would like to create an animation with a pixel moving along a line step by step.
Something that does what the following snippet does, but using a `path` + `animationPath` rather than a simple animation (so to be able to reuse the path)

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 15 21" fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
<rect width='1' height='1' fill='#000'>
    <animate id="1" begin="0s" calcMode="discrete" attributeName="x" values="3;4;5;6;7;7;7;7;8;9;10;11;11;11" dur="14s" fill="freeze" />
    <animate begin="0s" calcMode="discrete" attributeName="y" values="1;1;1;1;1;2;3;4;4;4;4;4;5;6" dur="14s" fill="freeze" />
</rect>
</svg>
```

I have done it like this, but it seems like the animation remains interpolated although I explicitly made sure to have it stepped setting `calcMode` to `discrete`

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 15 21" fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
<path d="M 3 1 4 1 5 1 6 1 7 1 7 2 7 3 7 4 8 4 9 4 10 4 11 4 11 5 11 6" id='p1'/>
<rect width='1' height='1' fill='#000'>
    <animateMotion id="0" dur="7s" begin="0s" calcMode='discrete'  fill="freeze">
       <mpath href="#p1"/>
    </animateMotion>
</rect>
</svg>
```

Can someone explain me what am I missing? According to documentation, the discrete mode should be supported for the `animateMotion` tag using a `path`. In general: how can I achieve an animation like the one in the first snippet by leveraging `animateMotion` + `path`?

Comment: Seems discrete to me when I run the example. Note that I had to make it bigger to see it at all.

Comment: maybe it's a browser issue, but on mine the second snippet is definitely not discrete. Which browser do you have @RobertLongson ?

Comment: I'm using Firefox.

Comment: This is a [known bug](https://crbug.com/662663) (also affecting WebKit browsers). To workaround it you'd need to manually define the `keyTimes` and `keyPoints` attributes.